# Embed Error Debugging

Tags: embeds

Is there a way to display debugging information for an embed tag?

I can't use the administrator template debugging feature since the page I put the embed tag into is only accessible to non-logged in users.

The problem with the tag is that its not showing for one installation and its showing for another installation which is a clone of the former.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply copy the content of the embed into another, stand-alone, template and visit that?

If there are parameters passed to the embed then just hardcode values into your test template.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't show anything. I will try it in a standalone template though, maybe it will show something.

Comment: If it doesn't show anything then ensure you are logged in as the super admin and have debugging turned on in your config.
You might also want to try taking bits out of the template and seeing if it loads. If not, take something else out until you find the bit that's causing the failure.
You might also want to post a bare-bones version of your template here in case anyone can see where the problem may lie.

Comment: Strange. When I am logged in as administrator, the embed contents show. But if I am not logged in(guest), then it doesn't show.